# How is `switchMediaPresentation` used?

Tags: hbbtv

It's not clear to me how is `switchMediaPresentation` supposed to work after reading the docs: https://www.hbbtv.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/HbbTV-SPEC-00260-030-ts_103464v010301-without-ETSI-branding.pdf

I'm trying the following:

```
// ... previous code

<object type="application/hbbtvMediaSwitcher" class="MediaSwitcher" id="MediaSwitcher"></object>

// ... More code

<script>
  document
    .getElementById("MediaSwitcher")
    .switchMediaPresentation(
      originalMediaObject,
      newMediaObject,
    )
    .then(() => {})
    .catch(e => {})
</script>
```

I'm getting error `document.getElementById(...).switchMediaPresentation is not a function`

Any idea from my fellow HbbTV developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the device supports switchMediaPresentation and that it's enabled for you? That API is very new, there aren't many implementations and the most widespread one only enables the feature for specific apps.

Comment: In this case I was using Firefox's HbbTV Emulator and it in fact didn't support this feature. After some time working on it I realized it. Thank you for your comment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

switchMediaPresentation, like lots of other features is optional to support.
Prior to use the switchMediaPresentation API you need to check if device implement it, for example by check of presence of "ta" element in the  xmlCapabilities property of the application/oipfCapabilities embedded object.